# How to Break json object in a for each

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can one split the below json example by different email in a for each loop? So the end result is two completely separate entities keeping there own objects and arrays.

This result comes from a sql dump but the sql connector alters the output, so I've had to parse that output in a for each loop of its own even though there is no loop it's all in one line.

```
[
  {
    "Email": "Steve@gmail.com",
    "Name": "Steve Larson",
    "ID": "1111",
    "Date": "2022-09-12",
    "Address": "10 Chicken Place",
    "Town": "Gatebody",
    "Postcode": "xxx 1xx",
    "Data": [
      {
        "Ref": "34546",
        "Transaction_Date": "2018-11-29",
        "Amount": 27.76,
        "Balance": 27.76,
        "Notes": "Beep1"
      },
      {
        "Ref": "34546v2",
        "Transaction_Date": "2018-12-24",
        "Amount": 27.76,
        "Balance": 27.76,
        "Notes": "Beep2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Email": "innis@gmail.com",
    "Name": "Innis Blitz",
    "ID": "3456",
    "Date": "2022-10-12",
    "Address": "33 Snake Road",
    "Town": "March",
    "Postcode": "cxc 3cd",
    "Data": [
      {
        "Ref": "078776701",
        "Transaction_Date": "2021-08-27",
        "Amount": 984.68,
        "Balance": 984.68,
        "Notes": "Yes please"
      },
      {
        "Ref": "078776701v2",
        "Transaction_Date": "2021-08-27",
        "Amount": 98422.6,
        "Balance": 98432.6,
        "Notes": "Please not now"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Would like to do a for each so it splits the above like so. The idea then for my to load the result of the for each into a template that takes arrays.

```
{
  "Email": "Steve@gmail.com",
  "Name": "Steve Larson",
  "ID": "1111",
  "Date": "2022-09-12",
  "Address": "10 Chicken Place",
  "Town": "Gatebody",
  "Postcode": "xxx 1xx",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Ref": "34546",
      "Transaction_Date": "2018-11-29",
      "Amount": 27.76,
      "Balance": 27.76,
      "Notes": "Beep1"
    },
    {
      "Ref": "34546v2",
      "Transaction_Date": "2018-12-24",
      "Amount": 27.76,
      "Balance": 27.76,
      "Notes": "Beep2"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
{
  "Email": "innis@gmail.com",
  "Name": "Innis Blitz",
  "ID": "3456",
  "Date": "2022-10-12",
  "Address": "33 Snake Road",
  "Town": "March",
  "Postcode": "cxc 3cd",
  "Data": [
    {
      "Ref": "078776701",
      "Transaction_Date": "2021-08-27",
      "Amount": 984.68,
      "Balance": 984.68,
      "Notes": "Yes please"
    },
    {
      "Ref": "078776701v2",
      "Transaction_Date": "2021-08-27",
      "Amount": 98422.6,
      "Balance": 98432.6,
      "Notes": "Please not now"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: They're split now?

Comment: no not yet, just adjusted my question to reflect what im trying to do,

Comment: But he's right, they're already split.  It's already in an array format.  If you want to split them into two variables without looping, I can provide an answer for that but it'll be a static set of expressions.

Comment: Think it was getting late and I forgot the current item bit. All good gents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results and I followed below process:

[image]

I have initialized your input as below:

[image]

Then i added for each control and send the output of previous step as input as inside of foreach loop, i have added send email action.

[image]

Outputs:

[image]

[image]

I have got tow jsons in two seperate emails as above.